# What does :convertprc means in terms of process

Tags: android

I an trying to write a [bound service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) in android using Messenger. I am able to successfully do that by following online examples. The way every one defines the service is as following:

```
<service android:name = ".ConvertService" android:process=":convertprc"/>
```

I am unable to find documentation on what **:convertprc** means as an attribute for process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on Service Element for the Android Manifest:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html

In the section labelled **android:process**

> If the name assigned to this attribute begins with a colon (':'), a new process, private to the application, is created when it's needed and the service runs in that process.